# Retrieve the data from database based on type

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Basically I have data in my DB as mentioned below :

[image]

And I am expecting the output as below :

[image]

So What I meant was, if a person fails/Passes  in all subjects I need to display only 1st row or else I need to display all the data of that particular person.

I can able to display the records if person pass and fail(George), but could not able to display if he fails/passes in all subjects (for Sam and John)

I tried by add some subqueries and group by and using LAG and LEAD functions but I could not able to achieve the result. Can any one of you suggest in doing so..

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by name, status) as cnt_status,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by no) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or
      cnt <> cnt_status;
```

You could also do this without window functions:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.status <> t.status
             ) or
      t.no = (select min(t2.no) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Comment: After doing some changes as per my need I got what I required. Thanks it helped me a lot